# Issue with Content Based routing

Tags: java, apache-camel, placeholder

Hi I am trying to route to two different velocity template files based on a header value

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:csi:aaa").bean(bbb.class, "transform").wireTap("direct:auditlog:request").choice()
            .when().simple("${in.header.ccc == 'true'}").to("velocity:vm/ddd.vm").otherwise()
            .to("velocity:vm/eee.vm").end().to("http4://headeruri?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class).wireTap("direct:auditlog:response")
            .bean(bbb.class, "processResponse").routeId("zzzRouteBuilder");
}
```

the exchange has the *ccc* in the header and it is true but still it is taking eee.vm

Comment: What is in.header.ccc ? Is it a field? Where do you set this field? You need to flesh out the question a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the simple definition, it should be:

```
.when().simple("${in.header.ccc} == 'true'")
```

Or a simpler:

```
.when().simple("${in.header.ccc}")
```